# calculate colunm powerBI datediff of childs row in table with parent row table

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have a problem. i'm new on power BI

i have a table that contains childs and parent rows, and in other table i have only the child rows every row of both tables have start date and end date. i have to calculate total diff time of parent row and child rows. i have the following DAX expression:

```
tiempoResolucion = DATEDIFF(incidencias[fecha_inicio];incidencias[fecha_fin]; MINUTE) + CALCULATE(
SUMX(
incidenciasHijas;
DATEDIFF(incidenciasHijas[fecha_inicio];incidenciasHijas[fecha_fin]; MINUTE)
),
incidencias[id_padre] <> BLANK()
)
```

it returns me the following error:

A circular dependency was detected: incidencias[tiempoResolucion], incidenciasHijas[fecha_fin], incidenciasHijas[incidenciasHijas-5d28653b-e27d-4379-bc24-c4258834cb23], incidencias[tiempoResolucion].

somebody can tell me how can i solve this and why this error?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it

```
tiempoResolucion = 
DATEDIFF(incidencias[fecha_inicio];incidencias[fecha_fin]; MINUTE) + CALCULATE(
SUMX(
incidenciasHijas2;
DATEDIFF(incidenciasHijas2[fecha_inicio];incidenciasHijas2[fecha_fin]; MINUTE)
);
incidenciashijas2[id_padre]
)
```